# get eventx, eventy for a button which is clicked by jQuery click()

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events

I have a button `<button  id="get_eventxydiv"> click</button>`  and I want to get clientx and clienty value for this when clicked.

```
$('#get_eventxydiv').on('click', get_eventXY);
```

And I want it onload itself. So I am clicking the button onload.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { $('#get_eventxydiv').trigger('click'); });
```

and here is the click function

```
function get_eventXY(event)
{
  eventx=event.clientX;
  eventy=event.clientY;
  alert(eventx+" "+eventy);
}
```

But onload it alerts:

> undefined undefined

How to make it work? Any help please

Comment: Is `get_eventXY` defined within `.ready()`?

Comment: Accepted Yours as answer because mine is derived from Yours  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.trigger()` does not trigger native `HTMLElement.click()` event. Call [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function get_eventXY(event) {
    console.log(event)
    eventx = event.clientX;
    eventy = event.clientY;
    alert(eventx + " " + eventy);
  }
  $('#get_eventxydiv').on('click', get_eventXY);
  $('#get_eventxydiv')[0].click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="get_eventxydiv">click</button>
```

Comment: It gives 0 0 onload, but when clicked the button mannually, it gives exact values

Comment: @vikram What is expected result?

Comment: It should give the value which is same as the value when clicked manually at the center of the button(or at somepoint of button)! Is it possible?

Comment: @vikram What value would that be?

Answer (score 1):

After workaround for sometime, got the solution, which is the update to @guest271314.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            function get_eventXY(event) {
                   var width=$('#get_eventxydiv' ).width();
                   var height=$('#get_eventxydiv' ).height();
                   var offset_org = $('#get_eventxydiv' ).offset();
                   var centerX = offset_org.left + width / 2;
                   var centerY = offset_org.top + height / 2;

                   eventx = centerX;
                   eventy = centerY;
           }
           $('#get_eventxydiv').on('click', get_eventXY);
           $('#get_eventxydiv')[0].click();
});
```